# Head of empty list

Tags: list, function, f#

I'm trying to make a function which returns a list of the first element of each sub-list, including empty lists being returned as [].

```
let firstCol (lst: 'a list list) =
  List.map List.head lst
```

This works as long as there are no empty lists, but I get the following error message when my input includes an empty list:

```
System.ArgumentException: The input list was empty.
```

How do I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `List.tryHead` that returns `Option<'a>`: `Some value` or `None` depending on presence of head in list

Comment: How you go about this depends on what result you need. What should `firstCol [[]]` return?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Just [], and firstCol [[1;2];[];[3;4]] should return [1;[];3] etc. 
The List.tryHead option others suggested, where it returns None, or ignore the empty lists is not a viable solution for me. Ty

Comment: `[1; []; 3]` is not a thing. A list can't contain elements of different types.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `List.tryHead` or write your own function from the ground, or with helpers like `List.fold`/`List.foldBack`.

If you do `List.tryHead` you get an option as a result, either `Some` element, or `None` if the list is empty. So you must think what happens in the `None` case. You cannot return an empty list for a sub-list, because a list must have the same type. But you could for example skip empty lists. Or just keep the Option. As it indicates when a list was empty.

```
let xs = [[1;2;3];[];[4;5;6];[];[7;8;9]]

printfn "%A" (List.map List.tryHead xs)
```

returning

```
[Some 1; None; Some 4; None; Some 7]
```

You could skip the empty sub-lists

```
printfn "%A" (List.choose List.tryHead xs)
```

so you get

```
[1;4;7]
```

or do it on your own, with `List.foldBack`

```
let firstCol xs = 
    let folder xs acc =
        match List.tryHead xs with
        | Some x -> x :: acc
        | None   -> acc
    List.foldBack folder xs []
```

Or even more basic

```
let rec firstCol xs =
    match xs with
    | []           -> []
    | []::xss      -> firstCol xss
    | (x::xs)::xss -> x :: firstCol (xss)
```

The last version is not tail-recursive, but anyway, you should try and train to understand such a recursive definition. And be able to turn such a function into an tail-recursive on your own.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for can't be done with the signature you currently have. Consider this input:

```ml
[
    [1; 2]
    []
    [3; 4]
]
```

It looks like you're asking for the following output:

```ml
[
    1
    []
    3
]
```

However, that isn't a legal list in F# because its elements don't have the same type.

I think your best bet is just to use `tryHead` instead, as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: It would be reasonably to try to get `[ [1]; []; [3] ]` as the output in this case, I guess...

Comment: Sure, but that’s exactly what `Option` already does.

Comment: Yep, and in a much better way. I mentioned the above, because I suppose in some numerical processing languages (maybe??) where "everything is a list" taking the first element of a list might itself produce a list, so that may be what the OP was thinking...

Comment: `None` or `[]` are both valid representations, I say. Which one's better depends on what they are used for.